# jQuery .on() selectors

Tags: jquery

I'm binding events to a container div with jQuery's on() function and supplying a selector of ".myItem".

```
$container.on('click', '.myItem', { me: this }, MyClass.prototype.onItemClick);
```

Everything is working great other than the fact that child elements that don't have a class of "myItem" are still causing the event to fire. Is that the correct behavior? That the selector would match an element with a class of "myItem" AND its children?

```
<div class="myItem">
   <div>My Label</div>
</div>
```

From my experiments both of the `<div>`s above will fire the event. What I want is to a click on the child div to bubble up to the parent one with the class name, then the event fire for that element. I.e. inside the event handler, `event.target` should always refer to the `.myItem` element.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think the issue here is the behavior of the `click` event. You would be clicking both `div`s simultaneously, when clicking a child `div`.

Comment: You want only the element w/ the class name to cause the event to fire, but you want child events to bubble up? I'm confused--what do you want to happen if you click on the `My Label` text? And in the div around the text?

Comment: Yes, that is and was always the behaviour, since (most) events bubble up the DOM tree.

Comment: I want a click on the "My Label" div to fire the event, but bubble up so that event.target is the "myItem" div.

Comment: @Steve: Then you should clarify this in your question. Currently it sounds like you don't want the event handler to be triggered if a child is clicked on. That said, I don't think you can change `event.target`.

Comment: @Felix Kling, I can only apologize. It was an honest question. I didn't quite expect the community to be so aggressive.

Comment: No need to apologize. I have to, if my tone was aggressive. I just said this because in your question you stated "I only want the element that actually has the class name specified to cause the event to fire" which really is different than what you mention in your comments. Two of the questions picked that up and suggest you to stop the event from bubbling but it does not seem what you want. And in this light, the original question is certainly a duplicate, but your comment changes it a bit and I think it's a good question. *edit:* I noticed that your penultimate sentence actually states this.

Comment: I edited your question slightly to make this point more stand out. If you don't agree with my edit, please feel free to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want a click on the "My Label" div to fire the event, but bubble up so that event.target is the "myItem" div.

In this scenario, `myItem` is not going to be `event.target`.  It will be `event.currentTarget`.  See the [issue I filed](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11756) regarding that for more details.

Comment: +1 This as close as it can get to what the OP wants. I tried to replicate it but couldn't  until I realized I did not define the event handler with an `event` parameter, so `event` was referring to the original, global event object. I don't like Chrome sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

In order to get that functionality with clicking you'd need to stop the propagation of the click method on child nodes to keep them from bubbling up to their parents.

```
$('.myItem *').on('click', function(evt) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Live Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/J8jEe/

Comment: Your answer text is correct but does not match with your code.

Answer (score 0):

A click on a child object IS a click in the parent object too, so a click in the child will trigger a click handler for the parent unless you handle the click in the child and stop propogation of the event.

However, when using delegated event handling like you are, there are limits to stopping the propagation of the event.  Your event handler won't even fire until the event HAS ALREADY propagated up to the container that you attached the delegated event handler to.  So, so at that point it's too late to stop propagation through the elements that are below your container (as propagation has already happened).  You can stop propagation any further up beyond your container.

If you want a click on ONLY happen in the label, you can do something like this:

```
$container.on('click', '.myItem label', function() {
    // your code here
});
```

This will use delegated event handling and isolate the clicks to only those clicks in the label.

If you want the parent `.myItem` object from within that click handler, then you can obtain it like this:

```
$container.on('click', '.myItem label', function() {
    var item = $(this).closest('.myItem');
});
```

Comment: The first sentence is also true for not-delegated event handling ;)

Comment: @FelixKling - yes, but that's more obvious since only one element is ever involved in non-delegated event handling.

Comment: Oh actually we are both wrong. `event.target` is set to originating element, `this` is always set to the element the handler is bound to. Well, in case of event delegation in jQuery it is set to the element that is matched by the selector. Getting confused over here... :D

Comment: @FelixKling - OK, I removed that part of my answer.

Comment: No, in a delegated registration, `this` is set to the element that matches the selector.

Comment: I actually didn't see your comment jfriend00. My comment was actually in response to Felix King: "`this` is always set to the element the handler is bound to".

Comment: @Felix, yeah I didn't realize that until after my other comments. Originally I stopped reading, and commented, after the "always" part.